# shh.filter() function in go-ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum, whisper

I am using go-ethereum private network.

I am using the web3.shh.filter() and it is working fine.

I am not able to locate the filter() function in the code.

In complete go-ethereum folder, I am not able to locate it.

filter.get() produces output correctly with expiry time and all. But I am not able to locate "expiry" word in the complete folder.

Can some one help me to locate this.

Answer (score 1):

For the filters, it just `require`s the [`filters.js`](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/e4eb9606aa0aa10fd3eeb0a5e5d67c4fff43e814/lib/web3/filter.js) file, as per [this](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/e4eb9606aa0aa10fd3eeb0a5e5d67c4fff43e814/lib/web3/methods/shh.js#L25) line in [`shh.js`](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/e4eb9606aa0aa10fd3eeb0a5e5d67c4fff43e814/lib/web3/methods/shh.js):

```
var Filter = require('../filter');
```

The `.get()` function is in `filter.js`, [here](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/e4eb9606aa0aa10fd3eeb0a5e5d67c4fff43e814/lib/web3/filter.js#L202).

The filter code likely doesn't actually know what the `expiry` field is: it's probably just abstract data that is later formatted appropriately (for example, [here](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/e4eb9606aa0aa10fd3eeb0a5e5d67c4fff43e814/lib/web3/formatters.js#L240)).